# Qt Checking Login using Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, qt

I am using qt to create a user login. I am using Sqlite as my database and am stuck for some reason it is not working properly. I was able to corectly bypass the login screen only when typing in the first row from the database. Any other user cannot log in (row 2, 3,4 ... in database). I have been reading all kinds of posts for the past days and have not come to a proper solution. Here is my code. I have also tried creating a query through QSqlQuery and passing it into the QSQlQueryModel Object which did not work at all.

```
void MainWindow::on_login_clicked()
{
    QSqlDatabase m_db;
    QString path = "C:/Users/annea/Summer2019Database.db";
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    m_db.setDatabaseName(path);
    m_db.open();

    if (!m_db.open())
    {
       qDebug() << "Error: connection with database fail";
    }
    else
    {
       qDebug() << "Database: connection ok";
    }

    QString username = ui->username->text();
    QString password = ui->password->text();

    QSqlQueryModel *queryModel = new QSqlQueryModel; 
    queryModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM [User Database] WHERE Username= username"); //select the row of where the Username == username
    queryModel->query().exec(); //execute it (not really sure why or what this does
    if(queryModel->record(0).value(1).toString()== password) //if a row is found check column 2 for password
    {
        destroy(); //destroy current window
        if(queryModel->record(0).value(3).toString()== 1) //if id is equal to one log in as user
        {
            user.showMaximized();
        }
        else {
            dbManager.showMaximized();
        }
    }
    else {

        qWarning("Wrong Password or Username");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong. Instead of writing like this:

```
queryModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM [User Database] WHERE Username= username"); //select the row of where the Username == username
```

You might want writing like this:

```
queryModel->setQuery(QString("SELECT * FROM [User Database] WHERE Username = '%1'").arg(username)); //select the row of where the Username == username
```

Why? Because you are writing a query, and you probably want to check against the user name entered, not the string "username". Also, don't forget apostrophes when comparing.

In order to find more information which might help with your problem, you should read Qt's documentation regarding its' classes. Also, it would be beneficial to take a look into the SQLite WHERE clause and how strings are represented when writing queries:

1. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery
2. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-1
3. http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-where/
4. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: thanks for the response! Question, What exactly does  = '%1'").arg(username)); do?

Comment: @raaamonnn arg() is the method that replaces %1 by value of variable named by username. Does it answer your question?

Comment: So I just added '%1' AND Password = '%2' ").arg(username) .arg(password)); and it actually works lol. Why does this work? everytime you add an .arg at the end you need to add a %1 .. %2 ... ? Also, What is the point on doing queryModel->query().exec(); my code runes properly with that line and also when commenting it out.

Comment: @raaamonnn You could have even written just .arg(username, password) instead of ".arg(username) .arg(password)" to simplify your code. It works because you provide correct query which resolves to result you want to check against.  And if your code works without "queryModel->query().exec()", probably you shouldn't need to use it in this case (but you might want doing so in more complex queries), since it might so that Qt calls this method for you when "record(0)" is called. Regarding everything else, I think you should take a look into documentation. And finally, did I answer your question?